# Fire event when client connects to WCF-hosted endpoint

Tags: .net-3.5, wcf

What do I do in order to fire an event when a new client connects to WCF-hosted service?

EDIT: What I'm looking is to get an event when a new session is created or new Channel gets created for a client. Such as: for session closure I'm using:

```
OperationContext.Current.Channel.Closed += new EventHandler( Channel_Closed );
```

so what should I be using for session iitiation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're trying to accomplish is best done by adding a new [channel initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ichannelinitializer.aspx) to the service listener(s) after they are created.

Basically, you create a class which implements that interface, then you add it to the service host. If you're self-hosting this is pretty simple:

```
public class MyHook : IChannelInitializer
{
  public void Initialize(IClientChannel channel)
  {
    // Do whatever.
  }
}

var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), MYBASEADDRESS);
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), new WSHttpBinding(), MYSERVICEADDRESS);
host.Open();

// There will be one per endpoint; you can enumerate them if needed etc.
var dispatcher = host.ChannelDispatchers[0] as ChannelDispatcher;
dispatcher.ChannelInitializers.Add(new MyHook());
```

Since you are using the per-session instance mode, you will get a new channel created for each new session, the first time a client connects. The channel dispatcher is the object that's responsible for taking the newly created channel and associating it with a particular service object instance (does address matching, etc.). It will run each of the custom initializers on the new channel before your service gets hooked up to it.

Comment: Thanks! That does answer my question exactly

Comment: For additional infos see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/14/wcf-extensibility-initializers-instance-context-channel-call-context.aspx

Especially for WCF 4.0 the proposed way won't work because a Exception is thrown after the Host transistioned to the open state

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your set up - do you do "per call" conversations? Then you don't really get any "client now connected" message per se....

Do you do session-based conversations? Your "ServiceHost" class has two events "Opening" and "Opened", which you can hook into, especially if you self-host your service.

What exactly is it you want to achieve by trapping this event?

Marc

Comment: Session-based. Service host fires the Opened event when service host starts up, e.g.: on host.Open() call, not when new client connects

Comment: do you have any advice if it's InstanceContextMode.Single?