# Detect WCF client open channel operation

Tags: wcf

I read the article in [this site](http://winterdom.com/2007/04/wcfchannellisteners) related to WCF Channel Listeners. I suppose that (correct me if I'm wrong), after a service opened a channel, it is possible to detect a request of connection made by a client. In practice I would like to detect when the client calls the Open method.
Could you tell me how can I do that please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For everyone interested in this question, I had an answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232501/how-to-monitor-client-connection-to-a-wcf-service) post.