# WCF Detect When Message First Arrives?

Tags: wcf, event-handling, interception

I have a self hosted WCF 4.0 service with an HTTPS endpoint. I have method that writes some trace info after the message comes in. However, some messages are 400k in size, so there is a long wait conceivably between when WCF has it and my console app has it. How can I get a hook or interception layer in there so I can at least know when a message is first coming in?

I think there is a WCF Performance Counter related to this, so there must be some way to know...

Thanks for all ideas!

This is not the same as [Detect WCF client open channel operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236460/detect-wcf-client-open-channel-operation) , this is about knowing when the HTTP traffic first comes in. Maybe its not that I need to monitor things on my WCF service, maybe I need to monitor some other WCF layer that is intercepting HTTP. Can anyone say?

Answer (score 0):

What about making a custom `MessageEncoder` that simply wraps the default implementation, but overrides `ReadMessage()` and logs some information *before* calling the wrapped implementation (which creates a `Message` instance)? At this stage the full message isn't even fully streamed over the wire, hence it's a very early point of the processing pipeline. Obviously, however, you don't know anything about the message yet. But if you want to get a timestamp, that might be a convenient place to get it.

Answer (score 0):

One option is implement the [IDispatchMessageInspector interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx) for your service with your message size checking code in the AfterReceiveRequest method override. Your code [should look something like the code in this blog post.](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2007/08/23/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector.aspx)